# Problem Direction - Text Data - Conversation Classification

Tags: nlp, classification, text-classification

The problem

- I have a problem where I have text data that has been transcribed from a conversation. These conversations have been marked as a pass or fail in terms of compliance by a person, ie they have listened to the call and marked the call as passed compliance or not passed . I am trying to think of a way to use the text data in regards to analytics. The conversations are just text data from a staff member to a customer, so i was thinking of trying to turn this into a learning problem to try and score conversations in terms of the risk. To explain further, score the conversation as the probability that the call passed or failed based on the text data.

My Thoughts

- I was thinking of trying to create a model that can score new conversations based on previous labeled data as we have calls that have already been scored as a pass or fail. I am just not sure if this solution is possible given the current technology stack.

My Questions-

- **I assume the main question is, is there a correlation between the conversation text and a call not passing compliance. How would I be able to calculate this correlation**.
- Would this be possible, what type of data pre-processing would need to be done.
- I think as its text data the data pre processing is the most important part. Information of the pre-processing steps would be much appreciated.
- Is there an example online that can be used as a reference?
- Would there be any other analytics that would be more useful? ie. a different type of solution.  - what size dataset would be suitable, just to get started.
  If possible can you please add links to articles, tutorials, books etc.
  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, you should ask this kind of question on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. Short answer: this kind of task depends a lot on the data, but in general don't expect very high performance. I would probably try to collect expert knowledge (what do evaluators check exactly?) in order to decompose this into smaller and simpler problems.

Comment: @Erwan Thank you! This is very generous of you! I will repost the question on the correct forum. I am honestly just wondering how I would get started. I assume the main question is in regards to finding a correlation between conversations and non compliant/compliant calls.  How would i start constructing a project. Would you have some material, tutorials to reference?

Comment: Well it's a complex problem related to natural language understanding, and since it's not a standard problem (like question answering, machine translation, etc.) there can be many ways to address it and it's hard to know which one is the best. Technically there are available methods of course: you could try to train a simple text classification model, but general text classification cannot take the conversation aspect into account. The way I would start on something like this is to study the NLP literature, find if there are any similar problems which have been treated and how.